# string, класс, структуры C++

Tags: c++, строки, ооп, функции, структуры

Всем привет!

Помогите, пожалуйста, найти ошибку в коде. Прошу прощения заранее, если мой вопрос кажется вам глупым, я только изучаю с++ и никак не могу понять, что делаю не так.

Я писала лабораторную для института, суть: создать базу данных на основе структуры, а также управлять этими структурами, используя методы класса. Вывод на экран разных сообщений обязательно должен быть где-то вне класса (в классе не может быть cin, cout).

С проблемой я столкнулась уже в процессе создания базы данных (поэтому других функций пока нет). Я могу ввести название экзамена, и выполнение программы останавливается, хотя по задумке она должна попросить ввести еще дату, фамилию (и так всего 3 раза, т.е. мы должны заполнить 3 структуры, потому что введенный размер базы данных = 3).

Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void Message (int, int);
int EnterSize();
void AllFunctions();
int EnterNumberOfFunction();
string EnterExamName();
string EnterExamDate();
string EnterProfessorLastName();

struct myStructure
{
    string ExamName; 
    string ExamDate;
    string ProfessorLastname;
    bool isEmpty = true;
};

class Database {
    private:
        int dataBaseSize;
        myStructure* dataBase;
    public:
        void DoFunction(int answer) {
            bool cycle = true;
            do {
                switch(answer) {
                    case 0:
                        NewDataBase();
                        break;
                    default:
                        cycle = false;
                        break;
                }
            } while (cycle == true);
        }
        void NewDataBase () {
            Message(0,0);
            int index = 0;
            dataBaseSize = EnterSize();
            do {
                dataBase[index].ExamName = EnterExamName();
                dataBase[index].ExamDate = EnterExamDate();
                dataBase[index].ProfessorLastname = EnterProfessorLastName();
                Message(3,index);
                index++;
            } while (index < dataBaseSize);
        }
};
int main() {
    SetConsoleCP(65001);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(65001);

    Database newData;

    AllFunctions();
    newData.DoFunction(EnterNumberOfFunction());
    return 0;
}

void Message (int answer, int index) {
    switch(answer) {
        case 0:
            cout << "\nСоздание базы данных\n";
            break;
        case 3:
            cout << "\nСтруктурная переменная №" << index+1 << " успешно добавлена!\n";
            break;
    }
}

int EnterSize() {
    int size;
    cout << "Введите размер базы данных: ";
    cin >> size;
    return size;
}

void AllFunctions() {
    cout <<
        "\nДоступные функции:\n"
        "0. Создание базы данных\n"
        "\n...\n";
}

int EnterNumberOfFunction() {
    int answer;
    cout << endl << "ВВЕДИТЕ НОМЕР ФУНКЦИИ: ";
    cin >> answer;
    return answer;
}

string EnterExamName() {
    string ExamName;
    cout << "Введите название экзамена: ";
    cin >> ExamName;
    return ExamName;
}

string EnterExamDate() {
    string ExamDate;
    cout << "Введите дату экзамена: ";
    cin >> ExamDate;
    return ExamDate;
}

string EnterProfessorLastName() {
    string ProfessorLastname;
    cout << "Введите фамилию преподавателя: ";
    cin >> ProfessorLastname;
    return ProfessorLastname;
}
```

[image: Дальше процесс не идет, хотя потом мы должны вводить дату и фамилию преподавателя]

Может быть, это какая-то проблема со string?

(если есть замечания по поводу стиля, логичности\нелогичности, с радостью выслушаю!)

Благодарю за внимание!

Comment: String - это класс, а Вам, видимо, надо использовать базовые типы для хранения char ExamName[25] ... Иначе как Вы собираетесь в файл всё записвывть и читать из него. У Вас же база

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В строке  `myStructure* dataBase;` вы определили указатель, но не сказали куда ему ссылаться. Далее в методе `NewDataBase` вы обращаетесь к элементу массива: `dataBase[index].ExamName = EnterExamName();` , а так как указатель ссылается "в никуда" - при выполнении этого участка получаете ошибку.
Чтобы этого избежать необходимо предварительно выделить память:

```
...
dataBaseSize = EnterSize();
dataBase = new myStructure[dataBaseSize];
...
```

Так как память выделяется вами, вами же она и должна быть возвращена, для этого необходимо добавить     `delete[] dataBase;` в нужном вам месте, учитывая вашу архитектуру приложения - лучше всего в деструкторе класса. Хотя архитектуру приложения тоже лучше пересмотреть.

P.S. ваши циклы `do...while` лучше заменить на обычные `while` (в первом случае) и `for` (во втором).

Comment: Спасибо огромное! А как стоит пересмотреть архитектуру, учитывая требования преподавателей (что cin,cout) не должны быть в классе?

Comment: @elediel ,Корректную архитектуру в одном комментарии не опишешь, но если в двух словах, то вы скорее пишите на "С с классами", а не на С++. В данном случае я бы реализовал интерфейс для взаимодействия с пользователем, а класс БД использовал бы его (или наследовался от него, зависит от задачи в целом).

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых у тебя `myStructure* dataBase;` - это один элемент. Тебе его надо заменить на массив элементов, например на `myStructure* dataBase[3];`

Во-вторых у тебя очень запутанная структура программы. Зачем делать ввод данных через `newData.DoFunction(EnterNumberOfFunction());` Такую структуру программы очень сложно отлаживать. Можно было сделать отдельный цикл, в котором вызывать метод добавления каждой записи. Например что-то вроде:

```
int answer = EnterNumberOfFunction();
do {
  switch(answer) {
    case 0: 
      newData.NewDataBase();
      break;
    case 1: 
      newData.NextFunction();
      break;
    default: // Условие выхода из цикла
      cycle = false;
      break;
  }
} while (cycle == true);
```

В-третьих `cin >>` со строками может ожидать ввода бесконечного многострочного текста. Надо заменить на получение 1й строки от пользователя. Не помню, как в C++ это делается.

Comment: `myStructure* dataBase[3];` - вы создаете массив указателей, которые все также ссылаются "в никуда". К тому же, т.к. размер массива заранее не известен, а вводится пользователем - это тоже потенциальная ошибка: если пользователь захочет ввести в 5 элементов, ему просто некуда их будет положить (даже если первые три вы как-то проинициализируете).

Comment: О заполнении массива говорится в ответе выше, потому не стал это расписывать.
Я привёл пример со статическим массивом - чтобы показать суть идеи. Понятное дело, что в данном случае нужен динамический массив.